# Window.open in each

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, each

I have problem with window.open(); in each. I need to open all language version of our site.
Script open only 5 - 6 language versions. Can you help mi with this problem ?

My code:

```
  var language = [
    "com-bg",
    "com-cz",
    "com-de",
    "com-hr",
    "com-hu",
    "com-pl",
    "com-ro",
    "com-ru",
    "com-ua",
  ];

  $('#OpenAll').on('click', function() {
    $.each( language, function(key, value) {
      if (actualLanguage != '' && actualLanguage != value) {
        window.open(url.replace(actualLanguage, value));
      }
    });
  });
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: what is `actualLanguage` in `foreach`???

Comment: Opening that many windows in quick succession is likely to be blocked by browsers anti-spam and security features. Why do you need this?

Comment: @Kartikeya in actualLanguage variable is language code from site where I am.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you. I do this, because we have lot of language versions of our site and I create extension for easy testing all language versions. Do you have some idea how do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.

replace:

```
window.open(url.replace(actualLanguage, value));
```

to:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: url.replace(actualLanguage, value)});
```